# Database design c# code first relationship ! Not many to many or one to many. Something else

Tags: c#, database-design, ef-code-first

Please look at the image below. Notice that Employee_ID for the Job_History and Employees table is the same. How do I express that in c# code first. What is that type of relationship called? I think is composite.... not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be one to many (employees.employee_Id to job_history.employee_id).

1. employees table has one primary key employee_Id,
2. job_history table has one composite primary key employee_Id and start_date.

Comment: oh i get it is a composite key like you said startdate and employee id brilliant. I know what to do now! Thanks.